# Pattern discovery in aws sagemaker

Tags: artificial-intelligence, data-mining, amazon-sagemaker

How can i run "Pattern discovery" on my dataset using aws sagemaker?
And of there is a simmiler term to
"Pattern discovery" because i cant find a lot of info about it

Answer (score 0):

The concept lies downstream of **Data Wrangling**.

As can be seen in the official guide '[Prepare ML Data with Amazon SageMaker Data Wrangler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/data-wrangler.html):

> Amazon SageMaker Data Wrangler (Data Wrangler) is a feature of Amazon
> SageMaker Studio that provides an end-to-end solution to import,
> prepare, transform, featurize, and analyze data. You can integrate a
> Data Wrangler data preparation flow into your machine learning (ML)
> workflows to simplify and streamline data pre-processing and feature
> engineering using little to no coding. You can also add your own
> Python scripts and transformations to customize workflows.

Here you will find a few tools for pattern recognition/discovery (and general data analysis) that will be used in SageMaker Studio: "[Analyze and Visualize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/data-wrangler-analyses.html)".

*The data scientist's advice I can give is not to use no-code tools if you don't fully understand the nature of the data you are dealing with. A good knowledge of the data is a prerequisite for any kind of targeted analysis. Try writing some custom code instead, to have maximum control over each operation.*